# Finding minimum weight perfect matchings for the same graph with slightly different edge weights

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory, perfect-matchings

Suppose I have found the minimum weight perfect matching (MWPM) for a given weighted graph, with say, the [Blossom algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm). Now if the weights of a small subset of edges are changed in the graph, how can I find the MWPM efficiently using the previously found MWPM? Certainly we can rerun the full Blossom algorithm to find the new MWPM, but intuitively, if only a small number of weights are changed, the new MWPM should be very similar to the old one, and hence it should be found much efficiently.

I searched a bit, and it seems like the problem is known as "dynamic matching problem". See [Dynamic Matching Algorithms in Practice](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.09099.pdf) as an example. The paper does not really address the problem above because a) they considered changing the connection in the graph, instead of the weights in the graph b) they considered approximate algorithm but I am interested in exact algorithms.

Another reference I found is [Fully Dynamic Algorithms for Maintaining Shortest Paths Trees](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0196677499910489), which considered the shortest path problem.

I am wondering is there any work consider "exact dynamic MWPM problem"? Any help is really appreciated!